# tesseract is giving highly inconsistent result

Tags: python, image-processing, tesseract, python-tesseract, tess4j

I want get result of match which is in format of image .
Below is the code I'm using to read text from image .I have used python code it also gives same result. How can i improve the output or is there any other better way for my problem .

```
     public String getImgText(String imageLocation) {
      ITesseract instance = new Tesseract();

      try 
      {
          instance.setDatapath("/tessdata");
          instance.setLanguage("eng");
         String imgText = instance.doOCR(new File(imageLocation));

         return imgText;
      } 
      catch (TesseractException e) 
      {
         e.getMessage();
         return "Error while reading image";
      }
   }
```

output is totally different of input

```
unnl lE

mam-m m,

mun-m, 1 ms "mm M

W urn-mm my A mm“ m

mus-1mm 1 m- m m

mﬁnlln um: ”mu“ m

ilk-M m.

mwnm mu 5 mm nu-

..mn. n w. tvhrzmr- m

2 rm.“- 0 w, mama: m.

mum-mp 5 mu mum n.

a bulb-h» m

tum-3mm nun mm,” M

3 mmn m; mum“ M

Ema W 7 a“. m

mzsm 5m mm»... m
Continue
```

input image is

[image]

Comment: You need invert image before OCR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should preprocess the image before running Tesseract (python code with opencv library):

```
import cv2

img = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
result = cv2.bitwise_not(img)
result[result >= 190] = 255

# To show the image
cv2.imshow("Threshold", result)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Resulting in something like this:
[image]

Additionally it seems the English traineddata handles the PUBG font poorly so you might wanna look into finetuning it:
[Training eng.traineddata for PUBG font](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TpD76k2HYms)